# Wilcoxon signed rank test - help on interpretation of pseudo median

Tags: interpretation, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am performing a Wilcoxon signed rank test in R, for two paired samples, where I have used the following:

```
wilcox.test(abs_error_gics, abs_error_sbp, alternative = "two.sided", mu=0, conf.int=T, conf.level = 0.99, paired = TRUE)
```

wherein I get the following output:

```
data:  abs_error_gics and abs_error_sbp
V = 48485000, p-value = 0.00000002249
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
99 percent confidence interval:
 0.00768364 0.02082407
sample estimates:
(pseudo)median 
    0.01426058
```

Obviously, I can reject the null hypothesis and say that the difference in medians is not zero. However, from the following table:

[image]

what I want to report in my result table, is how much larger the median on average is expected to be for GICS, compared to SBP, in the pairwise difference row. However, I am under the impression that this pairwise difference median, CANNOT exceeed the simple difference of medians? i.e. the simple difference from my table is 0.9%. From the R code I posted, I used paired = TRUE, since both GICS and SBP comes from the same underlying data. Doing this, yielded a pseudo-median larger than the simple difference, which should not be possible in my opinion? However, running it again with paired = FALSE, I get a pseudo-median of 0.89% (i.e. smaller than the simple difference). Can someone explain if my thinking is correct, or?

My data can be found here:

[Link to dataset](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/3b74a6b14b5ecd6e153ce2f309aa3120/APE%202004-2018%20EV%20ebit.csv)

Comment: "*I can reject the null hypothesis and say that the difference in medians is not zero*"

This is an error made in many books. The statistic in question is not the difference in medians but the median of pairwise averages of the pair-differences (including each pair-difference with itself). It's possible to construct examples where the sample medians are *identical* but the test rejects the null.

Comment: Some relevant posts:

1. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270889/how-is-the-confidence-interval-built-when-executing-the-wilcoxon-test-in-r/

2. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299606/what-can-we-say-when-the-wilcoxon-signed-rank-paired-test-shows-significance-but/

3. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348057/wilcoxon-signed-rank-symmetry-assumption

Comment: I am sorry, but I lost it after ... "averages of the pair-differences". My thinking was, that the median of pairwise averages is simple; I simply create a vector which takes the average between x and y, and take the median of this vector. But what comes after that, I cannot understand. Can you help?

Comment: You have the order of operations reversed ("The A of B of C" means do C then B then A). $\,$ **Step1**. Take pair-differences, creating a new set of data. $\,$ **Step 2**. Take values from this new set two at a time (for $i\leq j$), to create all possible pair-averages (including $i=j$) $\,$ **Step 3**. Calculate the median of those pair average. That's the Hodges-Lehmann one-sample estimator, applied to the pair-differences. There's a corresponding population quantity to this in the population of pair-differences.

Answer (score 1):

From `?wilcox.test`:

> Optionally (if argument conf.int is true), a nonparametric confidence
>   interval and an estimator for the pseudomedian (one-sample case) or
>   for the difference of the location parameters x-y is computed. (The
>   pseudomedian of a distribution F is the median of the distribution of
>   (u+v)/2, where u and v are independent, each with distribution F. If F
>   is symmetric, then the pseudomedian and median coincide. See Hollander
>   & Wolfe (1973), page 34.) Note that in the two-sample case the
>   estimator for the difference in location parameters does not estimate
>   the difference in medians (a common misconception) but rather the
>   median of the difference between a sample from x and a sample from y.

Comment: Thank you for providing the input from the manual. I have read it previously, but am still having a hard time figuring out if it's the statistic I want to report. I want a statistic that says the median will, on average, be 1.4 percentage points (since data is percentages) larger for x compared to y. Is that what the pseudo median gives me?

Comment: Look at posts that @Glen_b linked to in his comment

Comment: I have read all the posts, but to no avail. I updated my post with additional info, where I concretized my question.